# Sh Permission denied

Tags: bash, shell, embedded-linux

Below code embedded in executable.
i have placed the executable in /usr/bin/ directory with 777 permission given to the executable.

I am using beagle bone black. when i try to execute the linux applicaion

```
/usr/bin/app
```

which in turn calls internally the script Chk_File.sh fails. throws an error permission denied sh:Chk_File.sh.

```
if(!(system("ls /home/ubuntu/Desktop/BIN/BB")))
    {
    /* Test Path : remove after testing */
    dw_flag = system("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/BIN/BB/Chk_File.sh");//Call to execute Script
    dw_flag = WEXITSTATUS(dw_flag); 
    }
```

i have tried giving the chmod 777 permission at all places still it fails.

this is the script

```
#!/bin/sh


<<BB_SCRIPT_INFO

    This Script Will Check if required files are placed in the directory

BB_SCRIPT_INFO



ret_val=0

DIR=$(dirname $0) ;


echo $DIR

if [ ! -f $DIR/ACTION_TAG.txt ]
then
  echo " ACTION_TAG NOT PRESENT "
else
    ret_val=1       
fi

echo $ret_val
exit $ret_val
```

Please advise how can i get rid of this error.

Comment: What are the permissions on `Chk_File.sh`?

Comment: i have done chmod 777 Chk_File.sh

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 358 2014-04-19 17:49 ChkBB_File.sh

Comment: That's strange. If you did `chmod 777`, the permissions should be `rwxrwxrwx`, not `rwxr-xr-x`. But either way, you should be able to execute the script.

Comment: Are you looking at the right file? Your program uses `Chk_File.sh`, not `ChkBB_File.sh`.

Comment: i tried doing it again but the output remains same.. what could be the issue

Comment: No... it is correct ... i checked..

Comment: So the code in the question is wrong?

Comment: Check the permissions on all the directories in the path to the script.

Comment: there are many if..else if conditions..so there are files... with names Chk_File.sh.. ChkBB_File.sh .. ChkDC_File.sh. None of them Execute.

Comment: root@ubuntu-laptop:/media/PENDRIVE/Hrishi/19-04-14-reflash/BIN/BB# ls -l
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   0 2014-04-19 16:46 ACTION_TAG.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 358 2014-04-19 17:49 ChkBB_File.sh
root@ubuntu-laptop:/media/PENDRIVE/Hrishi/19-04-14-reflash/BIN/BB# cd ../
root@ubuntu-laptop:/media/PENDRIVE/Hrishi/19-04-14-reflash/BIN# cd DC/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu    523 2014-04-19 17:49 ChkDC_File.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu  74044 2014-04-11 12:55 ER_IROM1.bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 288000 2014-04-11 12:55 ER_ROM1.bin

Comment: I have done chmod -R 777 /script directory... i think there is some thing with the executable..calling the script internally..i am not getting it

Comment: Using 777 permission means anyone can modify any of your scripts.  This is lethal.  It is a bad idea on your machine even if you're the only person who ever uses it.  Just don't do it!